# How to use Intel integrated graphic card for display and NVidia card for CUDA on a desktop

Tags: 12.04, intel-graphics, cuda

On my desktop, I have a GTX560Ti which I use for CUDA and display
I have installed the installed the nvidia driver and everything works fine

I have an Intel HD Graphics 3000 integrated in my CPU.
I want to use this graphic card for my display, instead of my Nvidia card.

How to proceed ?
How to install Intel Driver vithout breaking CUDA ?

My ubuntu is 12.04

Comment: A brief summary if you start with a clean Ubuntu (13.10, but should generalize): http://osdf.github.io/blog/intel-integrated-graphics-dedicated-gpu-for-cuda-and-ubuntu-1310.html

Answer (score 3):

The trick is to load nvidia card in to the device without module nvidia, because nsight don't need this module to debug. And I don't need nvidia module as a display.

Here is what I did:

I add the file named nvidia_cuda into /etc/init.d and make it executive by chmod +X

This is given by nvidia, but I commented the line /sbin/modprobe nvidia

```
#!/bin/bash

# /sbin/modprobe nvidia

if [ "$?" -eq 0 ]; then
  # Count the number of NVIDIA controllers found.
  NVDEVS=`lspci | grep -i NVIDIA`
  N3D=`echo "$NVDEVS" | grep "3D controller" | wc -l`
  NVGA=`echo "$NVDEVS" | grep "VGA compatible controller" | wc -l`

   N=`expr $N3D + $NVGA - 1`
   for i in `seq 0 $N`; do
     mknod -m 666 /dev/nvidia$i c 195 $i
   done

   mknod -m 666 /dev/nvidiactl c 195 255

 else
   exit 1
 fi
```

This file is from 
http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-getting-started-guide-for-linux/#runfile-installation
2.5.2. Runfile Installation, Step 6.

But first you need to verify that you have both cards as pci device. I enabled intel multi-display in BIOS to get this.

```
$ lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK208 [GeForce GT 635] (rev a1)
```

Answer (score 3):

I have succeeded installing CUDA on my laptop with HD4600 + NV860M + Ubuntu 14.04, I hope it will help you.

You just need to follow the official documentation ([Cuda installation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-getting-started-guide-for-linux/)). The Runfile works better if you want to keep the Intel Graphics for the display because it is the default option. The trick is to use **--no-opengl-libs** when running the runfile so your previous display settings are not overwritten by Nvidia Driver which cannot be used by X Server.

More details:

- Make sure you have a device iXXX (i915 in my case) for Intel
- Block the nouveau device if it exists
- Run runfile from runlevel 3
- Do not install the OpenGL
- Add Path and all should work fine

I have tried so many times with other solutions, it seems that the official documentation is the best way to do it. If my solution doesn't work for you, I suggest you to read more the doc, maybe you can find somethings interesting.

Hope you can find your way out soon.

Comment: You offer to install the driver from cuda-runfile ? Current version (367) of nvidia runfile driver installation binary does not provide this flag.

Comment: Excusme I was wrong about missing `--no-opengl-files` flag in cuda or driver runfile.

Answer (score 1):

install common Graphics driver package: It will select appropriate file for the display:

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-all
```