# ubuntu 14.04.02 stuck after installing cuda 7

Tags: 14.04, nvidia

I have ubuntu 14.04.2 with both nvidia geforce 860m as well as intel.

> **lspci**
>   00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 06)
>   00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor PCI Express x16 Controller (rev 06)
>   **00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)**
>   Audio device: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller (rev 06)
>   00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI (rev 05)
>   00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
>   00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #2 (rev 05)
>   00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)
>   00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev d5)
>   00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #2 (rev d5)
>   00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #3 (rev d5)
>   00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev d5)
>   00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #1 (rev 05)
>   00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM86 Express LPC Controller (rev 05)
>   00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 05)
>   00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 05)
>   **01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM107M [GeForce GTX 860M] (rev a2)**
>   08:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 (rev 83)
>   09:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 10)
>   0a:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device 5249 (rev 01)

in the system-> details i see "Intel® Haswell Mobile" in the graphics.
i want to install cuda. 
i downloaded cuda-repo-ubuntu1404_7.0-28_amd64.deb  from developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads
i followed the next link github.com/facebook/fbcunn/blob/master/INSTALL.md  and did:

> sudo apt-get install build-essential
>   sudo dpkg -i cuda-repo-ubuntu1404_7.0-28_amd64.deb
>   sudo apt-get update
>   sudo apt-get install cuda
>   echo "export PATH=/usr/local/cuda/bin/:\$PATH; export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda/lib64/:\$LD_LIBRARY_PATH; " >>~/.bashrc && source ~/.bashrc

then when i reboot the computer, the laptop gets stuck with the ubuntu logo just before login.
why is that? i tried to understand why is that, and got confused.
do i need to install nvidia drivers before doing so, or does cuda install kit already includes it?
i tried to install the drivers using ppa-xorg edgers following this link http://www.binarytides.com/install-nvidia-drivers-ubuntu-14-04/  .
i managed to install the drivers, and reboot. and then tried to install cuda again the same way and got the same problem.
or is it because i have hybrid gprahic, both intel and nvidia? if so i can fix it? 
each time it happens, i end up reinstalling ubuntu.
i only care about getting cuda working.

Comment: same problem descried here http://askubuntu.com/questions/631080/ubuntu-14-04-wont-boot-after-installing-cuda-7/632423#632423

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use the installer (.run file) from Nvidia's website and run it in text mode. I have almost the same specifications and here is what I have done for installing CUDA [[link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/253161/how-to-use-intel-integrated-graphic-card-for-display-and-nvidia-card-for-cuda-on/668409#668409)].

If you follow my steps, you will use Intel for display and Nvidia for computing. It has been working fine on my laptop for many month.